# Ninject -> Scan assemblies for matching interfaces and load as modules

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject

In earlier versions of Ninject.Extensions.Conventions, it was pretty easy to scan a directory for assemblies, filter classes by interface and then load all containing ninject modules.

```
kernel.Scan(scanner =>
    scanner.FromAssembliesInPath(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location))
    scanner.AutoLoadModules();
    scanner.WhereTypeInheritsFrom<IPlugin>());

public class MyPlugin : NinjectModule, IPlugin {

     public override void Load() {
          Bind<IRepositoryFromPluginHost>().To<MyPluginImpl>().Named("special");
     }
}
```

However, after I updated lately to the newest release, everything seems gone and I'm unable to

1. Auto load modules
2. Filter types by interfaces

Does anybody have a solution for this?

Answer (score 4):

There's still the https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.conventions extension.
However, the interface has changed, to something along the lines of:

```
kernel.Bind(x =>
{
    x.FromAssembliesInPath("somepath")
     .IncludingNonePublicTypes()
     .SelectAllClasses()
     .InheritedFrom<IPlugin>()
     .BindDefaultInterface() // Binds the default interface to them;
});
```

Update:
How about you bind all `IPlugin` to `IPlugin` using the conventions extension (as above), and then do:

```
var plugins = IResolutionRoot.GetAll<IPlugin>();
kernel.Load(plugins);
```

Comment: Yes, but that is not exactly what I intended. Your example loads all classes from assemblies in a certain path that inherit from a certain interface and binds the default interface. However, what I want to do is just loading Ninject modules as plugins from assemblies where the binding instructions are inside them.

Comment: Sorry that i got it wrong. I'll look into whether there is some way to achieve that. Ninject StandardKernel by default still auto-loads all ´IModule´ in assemblies beginning with ´Ninject.Extensions.´, so the code may be accessible.

Comment: Sorry it took me so long. I've updated the answer to show how we used to handle plugins. If you don't want the extra `IPlugin` bindings floating around, i would go with @Eric's answer.

Comment: In v3.2.0.0 of ninject.extensions.conventions, that should read "IncludingNonePublicTypes()" rather than "IncludeNonPublicTypes()"

Comment: @Xaniff: yes, it does. While grammatically incorrect, I've quoted the code correctly. There's nothing to edit for me here.

Comment: @BatteryBackupUnit Well, grammar aside, I'm telling you that I just typed your code into VS (as I was looking for a similar answer) and "IncludeNonePublicTypes" isn't an option for me. http://i.imgur.com/7G4T9Nq.jpg

Comment: @Xaniff: i think your screenshot contradicts what your saying. It actually shows IncludingNonePublicTypes with **None** and not **Non**! And that's the same that my code above shows...

Comment: @Xaniff however you're welcome to suggest an edit to the post so i can review it ;-)

Comment: @BatteryBackupUnit In my original edit, I mistyped the intended method name. Specifically, I was looking at "Include" -> "Including".

Comment: @Xaniff Oh alright. I thought it was about None vs Non. Thanks for the edit, I've approved it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the hard way, but something like this will get you a list of types that are derived from NinjectModule.

```
var assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies(); 
List<Type> types = new List<Type>();
foreach (var assembly in assemblies) 
{
    types.AddRange(GetModules(assembly)); 
}


    IEnumerable<Type> GetModules(Assembly assembly)
    {
         assembly.GetTypes()
              .Where(t => t.BaseType == typeof(NinjectModule));       
    }
```

To load your module try this.

(Activator.CreateInstance(type) as NinjectModule).Load();