# Ninject - register all implementations of an interface

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, ninject

guys I need what I think is a common scenario but can't seem to make it work. I want to register all implementations so Ninject retrieves them in a constructor:

```
public Handler(IEnumerable<IValidation> validations)
{
    // NationalIdValidation, PassportValidation, etc. are available here
}
```

Current registration which I didn't creates some bindings but querying *validations* from the codeabove retrieves no records:

```
Kernel.Bind(scan => scan.FromAssemblyContaining<IValidation>()
                .SelectAllClasses()
                .InheritedFrom<IValidation>()
                .BindAllInterfaces());
```

Comment: Initial glance shows different interfaces `IValidation` vs `IUserValidation`

Comment: You're right. I corrected it, it was a mistake in the question not the actual issue.

Comment: Are you sure your Bind() call is actually binding anything? Are all your implementations in the same assembly?

Comment: What kind of extension are you using there? Ninject by default has no overload of Bind() that takes a lambda expression.

Comment: One more question, are your classes not internal? Have you tried BindSingleInterface method?

Comment: @PMF The assembly is the same for all of them. In regards to the other question - I'm under the impression this is a standard Ninject API. I found the same usage elsewhere e.g.: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23629040/1032147

Comment: @Iaroslav All the implemetation classes are public. I'll try the .BindSingleInterface method and get back.

Comment: And what about `.InheritedFrom<IUserValidation>`?

Comment: @zmaten: No, it's not default, but it's defined here: https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Extensions.Conventions Could come in handy for me, actually.

Comment: @JanMuncinsky Forgot to change it in the question's example. It all fits in the actual code though.

Comment: This works as expected. You should post whole example!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Common mistakes:

1) The classes are not actually in an assembly covered by the convention

2) The classes implementing the `IValidation` interface need to be public *or* you need to add `IncludingNonPublicTypes()` to the convention:

```
Kernel.Bind(scan => scan.FromAssemblyContaining<IValidation>()
            .SelectAllClasses()
            .IncludingNonPublicTypes()
            .InheritedFrom<IValidation>()
            .BindAllInterfaces());
```

Also note that in older versions of Ninject this method was called `IncludeNonePublicTypes()` (None instead of Non).

For debugging purposes, you can also implement an [`IBindingGenerator`](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Extensions.Conventions/blob/master/src/Ninject.Extensions.Conventions/BindingGenerators/IBindingGenerator.cs) and change your binding to use that. Then set a break-point inside the `IBindingGenerator` to see which classes matching the conditions are actually found. If the necessary classes are found, then it can only be a problem of the `Bind...` part of the implementation.